# Trouble with Case Statements

Tags: sql, database, oracle, case

[Picture of the Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBH81.jpg)

I'm having trouble getting my case statements to work, this is what I have so far

```
Select Employee_id,First_name, Last_name, Job_id, Case Hire_date, 
From Employees
Order by to_char(Hire_date, 'MM') ASC, to_char(hire_date, 'DD') ASC;
```

I also tried

```
Select Employee_id,First_name, Last_name, Job_id
From Employees
Anniversary = Case
 When hire_date = sysdate - 2
 Then 'Day before yesterday'
 When hire_date = sysdate - 2
 Then 'Yesterday'
 End 'Anniversary'
Order by to_char(Hire_date, 'MM') ASC, to_char(hire_date, 'DD') ASC;
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do, with example expected output.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question:

```
Select
  Employee_id,First_name, Last_name, Job_id,
  Case
   When hire_date = trunc (sysdate) - 2 Then 'Day before yesterday'
   When hire_date = trunc (sysdate) - 1 Then 'Yesterday'
   when hire_date = trunc (sysdate) + 1 then 'Tomorrow'
   // etc etc
  End as "Anniversary"
From Employees
Order by to_char(Hire_date, 'MM') ASC, to_char(hire_date, 'DD') ASC;
```

`case` is just a function -- use it inline in your select or where clause.

When you use single quotes, that denotes a value.  Double quotes denotes a label (or field), which appears to be what you wanted with "Anniversary."

Also, instead of `sysdate`, which gives the date and time, I think you want `trunc (sydate)`.

That's the basic syntax of what you're looking for.  I'll also make note that your logic, I don't think, is right.  You need to take into account the fact that the hire date won't have the same year as the current `sysdate`.

This is a bit clumsy -- there is probably a more elegant way of doing it, but this is an example of how you can synch both the hire date to be in the same year as the current date.  Bear in mind, this approach is likely to backfire at the beginning and end of the year (ie 1/1 is only a day away from 12/31, but doing this will make it look like it's 364 days away):

```
select
  hire_date,
  to_date (extract (year from sysdate) || '-' ||
    extract (month from hire_date) || '-' ||
    extract (day from hire_date), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as cy_hire_date
from Employees
```

Hopefully this is directionally enough to get you to where you need to go.

Answer (score 0):

You have `when hire_date = sysdate - 2` twice.  That would be a place to start.  You also have incorrect syntax in your case statement.  It should precede the FROM clause.

Looks like Hambone has given you the answer.  Anyway, the whole CASE part of it should be understood to be analogous to a field that you select.  The AS can be used with any field: `select employee_id as ID`, etc.